Netty - msg not string
With Netty, what does the following message to the console mean:
msg class: class io.netty.buffer.PooledSlicedByteBuf msg:[PooledSlicedByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 215, cap: 215/215, unwrapped: PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 215, widx: 215, cap: 2048))]
msg not string
I am using the following handlers: SocketClientInitializer, LengthFieldPrepender,
LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder

You need to create a handler firstly:
@Component   
public class EchoServerHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<Object> {

      private static ChannelGroup channelGroup = new DefaultChannelGroup(GlobalEventExecutor.INSTANCE);

      public EchoServerHandler(){

      }


      @Override
      public void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx,Object msg)throws Exception{
        Channel channel = ctx.channel();
        SocketAddress address = channel.remoteAddress();

        // Get what you want from `ByteBuf`
        ByteBuf byteBuf = (ByteBuf) msg;
        Integer intValue = byteBuf.readInt();
        Byte byteValue = byteBuf.readByte();
       

    }
}

Then the initializer class is necessary:
 @Component
 public class ServerChannelInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {

    @Autowired
    private EchoServerHandler echoServerHandler;

    @Override
    protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
        ChannelPipeline channelPipeline = ch.pipeline();

        channelPipeline.addLast("frameDecoder",new LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder(10*1024*1024,0,0,0,0));

        channelPipeline.addLast("encoder", new StringEncoder());
        channelPipeline.addLast(echoServerHandler);
    }
}

Finally, to make your server:
@Component
public class NettyServer {

    @Autowired
    private ServerChannelInitializer serverChannelInitializer;

    /**
     * start server
     * @param hostname
     * @param port
     * @return
     * @throws Exception
     */
    EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    private Channel channel;

    public ChannelFuture start(String hostname, int port) throws Exception {

        ChannelFuture f = null;
        try {
            //init
            ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
            b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
                    .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                    .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true)
                    .childOption(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, true)
                    .option(ChannelOption.RCVBUF_ALLOCATOR, new FixedRecvByteBufAllocator(65535))
                    .childHandler(serverChannelInitializer)
                    .localAddress(new InetSocketAddress(hostname, port));

            f = b.bind(port).sync();
            f.channel().closeFuture().sync();

            log.info("======EchoServer start success!!!=========");
            return f;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("someting wrong:",e);
        } finally {
            bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
            workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * stop the server
     */
    public void destroy() {
        log.info("Shutdown Netty Server...");
        if(channel != null) { channel.close();}
        workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        log.info("Shutdown Netty Server Success!");
    }


}


I am only a client and all my data both ways is byte arrays. The program works fine and does not miss any data so I do not see what to expect in the echo handler.
